# Get latest hosted jQueryUI

Tags: jquery-ui

Does anyone host the lasted jQueryUI JS and CSS?  For instance, I can use http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js for the latest jQuery.  Google provides specific versions of jQueryUI such as https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js (see https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui for a list), but I want a link that always gets the latest.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js

This gets the latest 1.x version of jQuery UI from the Google CDN.

However, it is not always updated promptly - right now it returns 1.10.2 rather than the latest 1.10.3.  Still, this is the best way I know of to keep it up to date, it may just lag behind a bit.  It works with the jQuery libraries on the Google CDN as well.

I feel compelled to point out that it might not be the greatest idea to do this though, since you never know when an update is going to break or deprecate some of your code or dependent plugins.

Comment: This seems to be a good solution.  And I was about to comment that I too believe it is not necessarily a good idea, and then saw your edited post that says the same.  The reason I want it is for a "blank" template which I use to create a new page and test some new feature.  I never use it in production.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[jquerylatest.com](http://jquerylatest.com) will give you latest jquery along different hosts like microsoft, google, jquery. Bookmark it better, it'll help you in future.